# как правильно реализовать функцию в Андроид?

Tags: java, android

Я реализую подключение к приложению через гугл аккаунт. Как в любом приложении есть возможность создать аккаунт(Create accaunt) и есть возможность подключиться к уже существующему (Log in) - это 2 разных активити. И в одном и в другом должна быть реализована возможность подключения через гугл аккаунт. Как сделать так, чтоб не пришлось описывать одну и ту же реализацию в двух активити? Код обработки подключения длинный и дублировать его не хочется... Активити по умолчанию уже наследуют, значит наследовать не получиться. Я новичок, и меня учили что не правильно когда в java один и то же код дублируется, подскажите как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Реализовать класс, который будет отвечать за подключение к аккаунту `Google`, например `GoogleAccountConnection`.
2. Вызвать метод `connect()` класса в нужном месте в нужное время.

Comment: А как правильно, сделать и класс и метод статическими или создавать обьект класса там где нам нужно?

Comment: Нужно еще по коду глянуть можно ли все переменные определить как статик... Если нет то придется создавать обьекты, но тогда вопрос что затратнее для программы повторить код или создавать обьект?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, сделай их `static`